# JavaFX program terminates when Stage.show() called a second time

Tags: java, javafx, terminate

I'm writing a JavaFX program that doesn't show the stage (`Stage.show()`) in the `start(Stage)` function, but rather, other methods in the same class call `Stage.show()` to show the stage at a later time. If I try to call any of the methods which call `Stage.show()` more than once, the program terminates itself.

The first showing of the stage/window works as expected, and after I use the ✕ to close the window the program proceeds correctly. However, if I try to call `Stage.show()` again, even from the same method, the stage/window opens and immediately closes, terminating the entire program with it. There is no error: I'm using Eclipse and the exit code is 0, suggesting successful program completion. I don't know what is different the second time that makes the program think it should terminate.

My program is directed by a command system that I built into it, and the command system is paused during the opening of the window or else the window crashes. Because of this, I have no other way of closing the window than the ✕. The `Stage.setonHidden()` restarts my command system.

Any insights into why closing and reopening a stage might cause the entire program to terminate would be appreciated.

This is a whittled down version of my program:

```
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    
    public class Example extends Application{
        
        static BorderPane mainPane = new BorderPane();
        static Scene scene;
        static Stage stage;
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            launch(args);
        }
        
        public void start(Stage newStage) {
            stage = newStage;
            scene = new Scene(mainPane, 640, 700);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.setOnHidden(e -> showBuild()); //Runs successfully when window is closed
            showBuild();
        }
    
        public static void showBuild() {
            stage.show(); //fails to show stage and terminates program when called a second time
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Create and post a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two distinct issues here. The first (and the one I understand best) is that the JavaFX platform, by default, will exit when the last window is closed. You can avoid this with a call to

```
Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
```

In this case, you will need to explicitly call

```
Platform.exit();
```

to terminate the application.

The second appears to be a question of timing. It looks like the `onHidden` event handler is getting closed before the window has properly closed. Consequently, you call `stage.show()` but then subsequently the underlying native peer window is closed, causing the window not to appear. This might be a bug.

A couple of workarounds:

1. Wrap the call in `Platform.runLater(...)` this will enqueue the call on the FX Application Thread and it won't get invoked until after pending event handlers have completed. This ensures the call to `stage.show()` happens after the window has completely closed.

   ```
    public void start(Stage newStage) {
        Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
        stage = newStage;
        scene = new Scene(mainPane, 640, 700);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setOnHidden(e -> Platform.runLater(Example::showBuild)); 
        showBuild();

    }
   ```
2. Use the `showingProperty()` instead. This appears to change only after the window has completely closed.

   ```
    public void start(Stage newStage) {
        Platform.setImplicitExit(false);
        stage = newStage;
        scene = new Scene(mainPane, 640, 700);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.showingProperty().addListener((obs, wasShowing, isNowShowing) -> {
            if (! isNowShowing) {
                showBuild();
            }
        });
        showBuild();

    }
   ```

Comment: hmm .. or maybe the hidden event is suboptimal to start with: what about using closeRequest and consume under certain conditions?